# How to add specific attribute (like "multiple") to Thymeleaf templates?

Tags: thymeleaf

I have this:

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="rest/controller/upload" multiple>
```

and I need to make it work in a Thymeleaf template.  I have the data-url part figured out but I keep getting an error on the word "multiple".  This is needed to allow multiple selection in the file selection window.

I have looked everywhere and have not come across an answer.

EDIT:

If you are not familiar, here is the "multiple" attribute.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_multiple.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Standard Dialect of Thymeleaf includes attributes that allow you to set these attributes by evaluating a condition, so that if evaluated to true, the attribute will be set to its fixed value, and if evaluated to false, the attribute will not be set:

e.g for `checked`attribute:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="active" th:checked="${user.active}" />
```

you have to use:
**`th:multiple`**

e.g

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" th:multiple="{condition}">
```

see a tutorial [here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/usingthymeleaf.html).

Comment: Just a side note. As long as your attribute does not need processing you can also use them directly as in your example name="active". The issue with the multiple is that Thymeleaf needs valid Xhtml syntax and this means no-value attributes are not allowed. The fix here means you write multiple="multiple".